# Hazm: POSTagger(): ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type

Tags: nltk, python-3.6, text-mining, pos-tagger, farsi

I have got an error for running the below code. May you give me some help?

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from hazm import *

tagger = POSTagger(model='resources/postagger.model')
tagger.tag(word_tokenize('ما بسیار کتاب موانیم'))
```

Error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ArgumentError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-1d74d781e0c1> in <module>
1 tagger = POSTagger(model='resources/postagger.model')
----> 2 tagger = POSTagger()
3 tagger.tag(word_tokenize('ما بسیار کتاب موانیم'))

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hazm/SequenceTagger.py in __init__(self, patterns, **options)
21 def __init__(self, patterns=[], **options):
22 from wapiti import Model
---> 23 self.model = Model(patterns='\n'.join(patterns), **options)
24
25 def train(self, sentences):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wapiti/api.py in __init__(self, patterns, encoding, **options)
283 self._model = _wapiti.api_new_model(
284 ctypes.pointer(self.options),
--> 285 self.patterns
286 )
287

ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

I am using ubuntu18.04 on windows 10. Also, I put mentioned files in resources file beside of code.
Python 3.6.9
Package of hazm

I have no problem to run Chunker one from this packege!

```py
chunker = Chunker(model='resources/chunker.model')
tagged = tagger.tag(word_tokenize('واقعا ک بعضیا چقد بی درکن و ادعا دارن فقط بنده خدا لابد دسترسی نداره ب دکتری چیزی نگران شد'))
tree2brackets(chunker.parse(tagged))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the Wapiti package! The wapiti does not support python.3.X and only works with python2.X! If you need a pos tagger, you should use other pos tagger packages!

Comment: Can you please, name a Pos tagger that is suitable for the Persian language?